# Is it possible to only list items from a search in a list box?

Tags: vb.net, listbox, searchbar

Is it possible to use a search bar to list a select amount of files? example being I am needing to list all files that have a 202 in front of the name. There could be at any time 50 with 202 at the beginning I want to list all 50. Currently I am listing all files and there are a bunch. It is in numerical order but was just looking for a cleaner easier way. Im currently using the following code

```
``listBox1.Items.Clear()
Dim directory ="C:\filepath"
Dim dirinfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directory)
list = dirinfo.GetFiles("*",IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
For Each file In list
    listBox1.Items.Add(file)
Next``
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listBox1.Items.Clear()
Dim directory ="C:\filepath"
Dim dirinfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directory)
list = dirinfo.GetFiles(*subroutineresult* + 
"*",IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
For Each file In list
    listBox1.Items.Add(file)
Next
```